# Is Co(2+) easily oxidised to Co(3+)?

Tags: transition-metals, oxidation-state

I think this question lacks some required informations but that's exactly what was given on my question paper. I thought of explaining this in descriptions of crystal field theory but I couldn't solve it at the end.

> Why is $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^2+}$ oxidized to $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^3+}$ easily?

Can anyone help me get the answer of this question?

Answer (score 4):

The author of the quoted question is obviously mistaken.

- The reduced form $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^2+}$ does not manifest significant reducing abilities and is oxidized with great difficulties only.
- The oxidized form $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^3+}$ is very strong oxidizer.
- The respective ox/red pair has the [standard redox potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page))  $E^{\circ}(\ce{Co^3+}/\ce{Co^2+})=\pu{+1.82 V}$, what is more than for most oxidizers. (Note that the $\ce{H2O}$ ligands are implicit in this.)
- The redox potential can be significantly shifted for other ligands. If they have stronger affinity to $\ce{Co^3+}$ than to $\ce{Co^2+}$, the redox potential gets lower. See the @Maurice answer.

Answer (score 4):

Poutnik should have added that the author of the mentioned sentence is clearly wrong.

But the author would have been right if he would have replaced $\ce{H2O}$ by $\ce{NH3}$. Matter of fact, $\ce{[Co(NH3)6]^{2+}}$ is easily oxidized in $\ce{[Co(NH3)6]^{3+}}$ for example by atmospheric $\ce{O2}$ molecules. The standard electrode potential for the reaction $\ce{[Co(NH3)_6]^{3+} + e^- -> [Co(NH3)6]^{2+}}$ is $0.1$ V. This means that the ion $\ce{[Co(NH3)6]^{2+}}$ can easily be oxidized by most common oxidizing stuffs, like $\ce{O2}$ or $\ce{H2O2}$

Comment: I have already exhausted my daily quota of "piece of crap" comments. :-)

Comment: Is there a daily quota of everything ? What does it mean ?

Comment: No, it was a personal joke. :-)